# How to fix text on a viewport C++

Tags: c++, graphics, turbo-c

I have a view port but when i take an input (cin) the char that i put is shown outside the viewport.

[image]

```
 setviewport(0, 0, getmaxx(), getmaxy(), CLIP_ON);
 margin = 100; 
 left = margin;
 top = margin;
 bottom = getmaxy() - margin;
 right = getmaxx() - margin;
```

Comment: A word of advice: abandon that compiler and move to modern c++ compilers.

Comment: I can't because this is what my school teaches us.

Answer (score 0):

Neither streams nor stdio is compatible with viewport in turbo c++. Use functions from conio.h or graphic  library (I do not remember which  one, I was using turbo c 25 years ago).

Of course using turbo c for teaching in 2016 is just insane.